# Facebook achievement does not show image in the ticker

Tags: facebook, image, achievements

I have added some achievements to my FB app. Everything works fine, but the images of the achievements are not shown in the ticker.

I checked the achievements with the URL Linter and the image property seems to be valid.

Does it take some time for Facebook to upload my images in their own system or have I made a mistake?

The images in the ticker have a URL but at [this URL](http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBn1EGI7WCL7Ka4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fakku.virgo.uberspace.de%2FFBSnake%2Fimages%2Fach%2Fach5friends.png) is no picture, when it should display the picture of the achievement. [Here](http://apps.facebook.com/snakespiel/) is link to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question:

Facebook does not use the images from a https recource.

I used this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://imgurl.png"/>
```

instead of this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://imgurl.png"/>
```

and it worked fine.